# Trouble Dragging Android Views

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn Android development and using the Android SDK in `Eclipse`.  I'm following a tutorial to build the `Main.XML` file on the Graphical Layout tab.  It instructs me to drag several Views onto the screen surface, including: `EditText`, `Button`, `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton`.

My issue is that these Views do not seem to drag.  I place the mouse cursor over them, press the right button but the Views are not captured for dragging.  There are other Views (such as Gallery) that seems to drag OK but those I'm interested in (to complete the tutorial lesson) do not drag.

Any help making this work properly would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried dragging them using the left button, rather than the right one? I assume you're talking about the mouse button, right?

Answer (score 1):

Forget about dragging Android elements. The best approach is to hand code them. Eclipse helps a lot, since it can show you a preview of what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks MEGA.  This is not Visual Studio is it.  I guess since the canvas is so small, it will not be too much of a burden to hand code these.

Comment: Yeap... Hand code them is not troublesome, and you get practice with them. Helps a lot. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to edit the properties of the button i do believe that eclipse lets you do that

Comment: Yes, the properties seem to work ok once the views are in place (added via Drag/Drop or XML hand code).  One funny is that new reference strings do not seem to be available until/unless a build is run.

Comment: thats odd ive never had that problem

Answer (score 0):

Goto Help->Check for New Updates and update

---

And then, You'll be able to drag n drop the View components onto your xml Graphical Layout. As @MEGA said, its advisable to hand code them. But, still as a beginner, I use Graphical Layout and the set properties using the Properties tab, which is more handy (since we donno what each property is for!)

Comment: "Goto Help->Check for New Updates and update" I assume you meant go to Eclipse Help and select Software Updates and then click the Update button.  I did this and got "Nothing to Update"